# select specific values ​in a dictionary that has values ​as arrays, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary on python, i.e.,

```
print(data)

{'train':{'X':  id     date      city       tcar  
                1      202012     LA         1
                12     202012     LA         1 
                51     202012     TX         3  
                ...      ....
[10000 rows x 4 columns], 
'y':array([0,0, ...,0,0], dtype=int32)}, 
'test':{'X':  id      date      city       tcar  
              132    202011      LA          1
              121    202011      LA          1
              441    202012      LA          2
               ...     

   [5000 rows x 4 columns], 
 'y':array([0,0, ...,0,0], dtype=int32)}}
```

I am not used to occupying this type of data. But if I have a python dictionary, how can I choose only particular values ​​from a column? for example, I want only the persons with tcar greater than 2. or create a new dictionary from it with this new condition

If this were a dataframe, it would be easier, since I can occupy the LOC function, but since it is a dictionary, I don't know what to do.

Error:
[image: Error]

Comment: If I'm interpreting your output right, data is a dict where `data["train"]["x"]` is a dataframe where you can index it as you described. `data["train"]["y"]` is a 1-d numpy array, so you would need to be careful to index into it using the indices from the dataframe if you need the corresponding `y` values. The same story goes for the data under `data["test"]`.

Comment: @rchome Completely correct, that's why I don't know what to do, if you could help me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd  

# create additional function to filter values of dictionary
def filter_dataframe(dx: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return dx[dx["tcar"] > 2]

# dict comprehension to iter over dict items and apply helper func
data_filtered = {k: filter_dataframe(v) for k,v in data.items()}
```

EDIT:

```
In [11]: dd = {"a": pd.DataFrame(data={"c1":[1,2,3], "c2":["a","b","c"]})}

In [12]: id(dd)
Out[12]: 140383605650240

In [13]: def hello(dx):
    ...:     return dx[dx["c1"] > 1]
    ...:

In [14]: dd2 = {k:hello(v) for k,v in dd.items()}

In [15]: dd2
Out[15]:
{'a':    c1 c2
 1   2  b
 2   3  c}

In [16]: dd2["a"]
Out[16]:
   c1 c2
1   2  b
2   3  c

In [17]: id(dd2)
Out[17]: 140383605877824

In [18]: id(dd["a"])
Out[18]: 140383606001040

In [19]: id(dd2["a"])
Out[19]: 140383558174080
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will return the same "filtered" dictionary

Comment: it will return a new object = new dictionary after filtration. Author wants to return new dictionary. Of course, to avoid operations on same dictionary witch is mutable and on same dataframes we can implement copy with deepcopy.

Comment: Thanks!, I think it works fine, thank you very much! but I have a problem that says that the variable "tcar" is not defined, and I don't understand why

Comment: can you show your code please giving this error? you shall access tcar column in this way: data["train"]["X"]["tcar"] as you have nested dictionary!

Comment: Ok, I edit my question